# Bootstrap carousel ( TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel' )

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get this every time when i call this   `$('.carousel').carousel();` on .carousel class that wraps everything

I added all code here so you can check http://jsfiddle.net/m5HBa/

When I try on my localhost I get

```
Bootstrap carousel ( TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel' )
```

I really have nothing else to try, I made sure to:

1. Include latest jquery before bootstrap
2. Bootstrap.js does include carousel object ( by default )
3. My code is within `document.ready()`

Any suggestions really appreciated

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools (hit F12, you'll need to install Firebug if you're using Firefox) to check that the js files are actually being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you use the right syntax:

```
<div class="carousel-inner"> <!-- All slides go inside .carousel-inner -->
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://i.imm.io/1g9kc.png" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption">aaaaa</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.imm.io/1g9kF.png" alt="..." />
        <div class="carousel-caption">gggggg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `href` of the `.carousel-control` links and the `data-target` of your indicators has to be `id` of your carousel. You originally had `#carousel-example-generic` but you carousel's `id` is `#carousel-example-captions`.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/m5HBa/2/

Comment: ahh yess man thanks :) I had wrong markup, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

First of all you gonna need to set up the "id" of your Indicators and Controls, with the same "id" you put on first div of your carousel.

After that, all data you need to rotate at the carousel, will need to be inside the tag   by the tag  . What you did was put 2 ""carousel-inner"  at the code.

Here is a code that may work for you.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://i.imm.io/1g9kc.png" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">aaaaa</div>
    </div>
     <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imm.io/1g9kF.png" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">gggggg</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/img/bootstrap-mdo-sfmoma-01.jpg"     alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">ccccc</div>
    </div>
 </div>

<!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>

</div>
```